# clipboardjs copy the html contents of a div to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I trying copy the html contents of multiple divs using [zenorocha clipboardjs](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js) javascript plugin. Please don't post other alternatives as I would like give this plugin a go, as it seems solid on the browsers that I want to cover.

I've looked at [this issue](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/321) on zenorocha's github, but this code just seems to return an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor`.

```
new Clipboard('.copy', {
    text: function() {
        var htmlBlock = document.querySelector('.yourSelector');
        return htmlBlock.innerHTML;
    }
});
```

I've created an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/qLord78p/) if anyone can help me use [clipboardjs](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js) to copy the html content of a div.

**JS**

```
// copy to clipboard
new Clipboard('.copy');
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content_1">
   <div><b>Heading Post 1</b></div>
   <div>Blah, blah, blah</div>
</div>

<button class="copy" data-copy-element="content_1">
   Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

I've made up a new data attribute called `data-copy-element` as there will be multiple buttons and content blocks on a single page.

See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/qLord78p/

Is this actually possible using [zenorocha clipboardjs](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Clipboard` is a native class, accessible through (among other places) [Chrome's Clipboard API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi).

If you want to get that code to work, change `Clipboard` to `ClipboardJS`. In fact, that's [even how `ClipboardJS` documentation calls it](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js). This works just fine:

```
new ClipboardJS('.copy', {
    text: function() {
        // based on your fiddle, you may need to replace this selector, too.
        var htmlBlock = document.querySelector('.yourSelector');
        return htmlBlock.innerHTML;
    }
});
```

Comment: Well spotted... can't believe I didn't see that, thanks i'm going have a go with this

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code, I used a bit of jQuery to get the specific element related to the copy button.

**JS**

```
new ClipboardJS('.copy', {
    text: function(trigger) {
        elem = $(trigger).data('clipboard-element');
        var htmlBlock = document.querySelector(elem);
        return htmlBlock.innerHTML;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content_1">
   <div><b>Heading Post 1</b></div>
   <div>Blah, blah, blah</div>
</div>

<button class="copy" data-clipboard-element="#content_1">
   Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/j2masp3u/